# Buffering a large 2D array with Node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to buffer a 2D array. My 2D array consists of floating point numbers e.g:

```
[
    [ 121093.28125, 38477.87890625, 41.57999801635742],
    [ 13.859999656677246, -16.51999855041504, 51.20000076293945 ],
    ...
]
```

It can be quite large, up to 1 million in length. I need to send this to a child process in node by buffering the array.

My code is:

```
// dataAsNumbers is the 2D array thats 10,000 in length
var buf = new Buffer(dataAsNumbers);

child.stdin.write(buf);
```

And in my child process:

```
process.stdin.on('data', function(buf) {

    console.log('buf.length is ', buf.length);

    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buf.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
        view[i] = buf[i];
    }

    console.log('ab[0] is ', ab[0]);

    process.exit(0);
});
```

However the array buffer is undefined:

```
buf.length is  10000

ab[0] is  undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you defining array ab, can you paste that code as well

Comment: Its there: var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buf.length)

Comment: In process.stdin.on

Comment: aah sry missed that part

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem like the right way to convert a 2D array to Buffer.
I tried with a 10,000 x 10,000 array but my buf.byteLength is only 10,000 which is not right.

If I do each row, then it works, however I lose precision.

If you have to do it row by row, then your best bet is to use JSON:

```
// i from 0 - 10,000, send buf to child
var buf = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(dataAsNumbers[i]));
```

Inside the child process :

```
var dataAsNumbers[i] = JSON.parse(buf.toString());
```

I'm up voting this question in case some one has a better solution.

Comment: A 10,000 by 10,000 array will have a length of 10,000 - the length properties counts each of the array entries as 1

Comment: how about byteLength?

Comment: Im not sure, i'll check

Comment: I originally meant to write byteLength, mine is still 10,000. makes no sense, it's all zeroes, try with a simple array such as [1,2,3,4]